# Warning when converting to `int' from `double'

Tags: c++, int

How do you get the return type to come back as a double for this expression: `a = 2 * NUM + z;`?

Here is my full program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
const int NUM = 10;
const double x = 20.5;

int a, b;

double z;

char grade;

a = 25;

cout <<"a = " <<a <<endl;

cout <<" Enter two integers : ";

cin >> a >> b;

cout << endl;

cout << " The numbers you entered are "

     <<a <<" and " <<b <<endl;

      z = x + 2 * a - b;

      cout <<"z = " <<z <<endl;

      grade = 'A';

      cout <<"Your grade is " <<grade <<endl;

      a = 2 * NUM + z;

      cout << "The value of a = " << a <<endl;

      return 0;

}
```

Comment: You should accept one of the answers below so the question shows up as answered instead of changing the subject title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare `a` to be a `double` instead of an `int`.

```
double a; 
int b;
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You've defined `a` as an `int` so there's no way it can hold a `double` value. If you change the definition to `double a;` it should work fine.

Comment: This was a code example from the text book we're using and reviews say it's absolutely terrible lol. Guess I'll have to manage, thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `z` is a `double` so `2 * NUM + z` is also a `double`, but you assigned the value to `a` which is an `int`. I'm not really what you are trying to do here; if you are trying to store the value of `2 * NUM + z` in `a` with truncation, then you should add a cast: `a = static_cast<int>(2 * NUM + z);` OTOH, if you don't want truncation but want to store the full `double` value, then you need to store it in a `double` variable.

Answer (score 0):

From the standard, 6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions

.......

Otherwise, the integer promotions are performed on both operands. Then the following rules are applied to the promoted operands:

1. If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is needed.
2. Otherwise, if both operands have **signed integer types** or both have unsigned integer types, **the operand with the type of lesser integer conversion rank is converted to the type of the operand with greater rank**.

So, in the expression -

```
2 * NUM + z;
```

`NUM` is a of type `const int` which is of lower rank when compared to the type of `z` which is `double`. According to rule, `int` is promoted to `double`. The result of 2 double type operands will yield result of type `double`. But you are taking assigning the result to an `int` type, hence the warning. Changing the type of `a` to double should work fine.